# Lost passport and overstay for 1 year in the Philippines

Tags: overstaying, philippines, lost-documents, italian-citizens

I lost my Italian passport and have been overstaying for more than 1 year in the Philippines. Can anyone tell me what to do without getting banned? I can pay for whatever the penalty is. Thank you.

Comment: It is very rare that you can overstay in any country without getting banned. You will get banned, that is already certain.

Answer (score 14):

> I lost my Italian passport and was overstaying for 1 year and more in the Philippines.

Have you reported your lost passport to the Italian Consulate?

Are you registered in the A.I.R.E. system?

Getting advice from your consulate how to proceed with your philippine overstay would be the best thing to do after starting the process of getting a new passport.

---

**Sources**:

- [Registry of Italians Resident Abroad (A.I.R.E.)](https://www.esteri.it/en/servizi-consolari-e-visti/italiani-all-estero/aire_0/)

> - the possibility of obtaining the issuance or renewal of identity and travel documents, as well as certifications;

Comment: I don’t think AIRE is useful/relevant here. Italian embassies are happy to help even if you’re not registered. Even if in this case OP *must* be registered first, I don’t think it would be their primary focus in this scenario, but rather avoiding jail for an Italian citizen.

Comment: I'll add, if they _do_ require AIRE to get a new passport, the process of residence registration is identical to the one required to get the passport: they need to wait for a _nullaosta_ from the residency province in Italy. — I lost my passport in the US and it was not an issue at all to get a new one. I also was forced to register to AIRE in Bangkok to get a passport once, so I know from direct recent experience.

Comment: @fregante My assumption is you are already registered, the process may be swifter.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably to use an intermediary to settle the matter. There are agencies/lawyers that can help with regular, legal visa extensions so you don’t have to visit the Bureau of Immigration. My guess is that they might also help with cases like this one.

Keep in mind that:

- if they happen to catch you somehow (e.g. random checkpoint) you will be immediately deported
- the chances of being banned for 5+ years are basically 99%, unless you really find a good excuse (e.g. “I was in a coma for the last 13 months”)

Comment: No, a person will not be immediately deported. They will be transferred to the BI Warden Facility in Bicutan, Taguig. where they will remain while their case is resolved which could take from a couple of weeks to several years.

Comment: If a person is deported their details are placed on what is known as the Black List via a a Black List Order.  Black List orders do not have a expiry date but for overstays can be relatively easily lifted via a Motion for Reconsideration after some time has passed.

Comment: The overstay penalty for one to two years is approx 60000 peso.  Overstayer just needs to work with any competent accredited BI agent to come back into compliance.  There is a standard process in place for this but they need to get their passport sorted out first of all.

Comment: Being "transferred to a facility" is the first step of deportation, so not "no." It's not like you'll be able to go home and book your own flight if they catch you, that's what I meant.